# GNU Parallel only using one CPU Core

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu-parallel, multiprocessor

I'm running some training using GNU parallel. The training takes about 30 secs to run one iteration, and I need to run about 3000. The training itself can't be parallelized (at least not without considerable effort), however, I run this training with several different seeds, and all these seeds can easily run on different cores.

This is how I am using parallel -

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
parallel ./train.py config/config.yml _results/ \
--seed {1} \
::: {1..5}
```

When I run this, parallel puts all 5 processes on the same core (core0), and each of them has 20% CPU usage (as checked using htop).

If I run another set of training using the same command, 5 more processes get added to core0, and now they all show 10% CPU usage.

I am on Ubuntu 18.04

```bsh
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
          Kernel: Linux 5.3.0-28-generic
```

and Ryzen 5 3600

```bsh
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : AuthenticAMD
cpu family  : 23
model       : 113
model name  : AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor
stepping    : 0
microcode   : 0x8701013
cpu MHz     : 3868.329
cache size  : 512 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 12
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 16
wp      : yes
...
```

My current (non-)solution is to use taskset after starting the training to put each seed on a different core.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel does not control which core to run on, so I will expect these will also run on the same core:

```
bzip2 < /dev/zero >/dev/null &
bzip2 < /dev/zero >/dev/null &
bzip2 < /dev/zero >/dev/null &
bzip2 < /dev/zero >/dev/null &
bzip2 < /dev/zero >/dev/null &
```

If that is the case, something is forcing your shell to spawn all processes on the same core and you should probably find out what causes this.

But if `taskset` works, you can do this as a workaround:

```
parallel taskset -c '{=$_=slot()-1=}' train...
```